# Weird behaviour when assigning a char to a int variable

Tags: c++

Given this code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main() {
        int a;
        string b;

        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;

        return 0;
}
```

I tried compiling it with g++ and running it.
When assigning a char to `a`, at the first `cin`, the following instruction seems to be skipped.

Even if add two `getchar()` instructions between the last two lines, only the second `getchar()` seems to be executed.
Can somebody accurately explain what's happening at low level, which seemingly results in an apparent non execution of those lines?

**EDIT:**

Using this debug code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main() {
        int a;
        string b;

        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;
        cout << "a is "<< a << endl;
        cout << "b is "<< b << endl;
        getchar();

        return 0;
}
```

**INPUT** 
1test

**OUTPUT**
a is 1
b is test
* No getchar executed *

**INPUT**
1
test

**OUTPUT**
a is 1
b is test

**INPUT**
ttest

**OUTPUT**
a is 0
b is

**INPUT**
t

// Skips the second `cin`

**OUTPUT**
a is 0
b is

NOTE:
`getchar()` was not executed even once.

Comment: i tried the code, and both the cins seem to be working for me.How are you running the program? Which OS are you running it on? Are u using a terminal ?

Comment: I'm running it on Mac OS X through Terminal.

Comment: If you enter a `char` where an `int` is expected it puts the `cin` stream into an error state. Every operation with `cin` is a noop (no-operation) until you reset the state to good.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for! What do you mean by state reset? It is related to the non execution of getchar()?

Comment: Sorry, you need to call `cin.clear()`. This will clear the `failbit` (and `badbit`), so that you can read more input. You probably want to check if the read failed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, judging from your output.  The first is when you enter
`"ttest"`, the `cin >> a;` fails.  This puts `cin` in an error state,
where it will remain until the error is cleared.  And as long as it is
in an error state, all other operations are no-ops.  You really need to
test the results of the input before trying to use the values:

```
std::cin >> a;
if ( !cin ) {
    std::cerr << "That wasn't an integer" << std::endl;
    std::cin.clear();
}
std::cin >> b;
if ( !cin ) {
    std::cerr << "Where was the string" << std::endl;
    std::cin.clear();
}
```

(And don't use a non-initialized variable, like `a`, until it has been
successfully input.)

The second is that the `>>` operator only extracts the characters
necessary for its target: `>>` to an `int` will stop at the first
non-numeric character, and `>>` to a `std::string` at the first white
space (in both cases, after having skipped leading white space).  This
means that after something like `"1test\n"`, there will still be a
`'\n'` in the buffer.  And while it's generally a bad idea to mix
`FILE*` (like `getchar()`) and iostream, if they're correctly
synchronized, `getchar()` will read this `'\n'` immediately and return.

If you're reading line oriented input, the best solution is to use
`getline()`, and then put the line into a `std::istringstream` to parse
it.  So your code might end up looking like:

```
std::string line:
std::getline(std::cin, line);
if ( ! std::cin ) {
    //  Something unexpected went wrong...
    std::cin.clear();
} else {
    std::istringstream l( line );
    l >> a >> b;
    if ( !l ) {
        //  Format error in input...
    } else {
        //  use your data here...
    }
}
std::cin.get();  //  Wait for one more character...
```

Comment: Chosen this as the answer since it is the most exhaustive. JohnPS's answer is really good, too!

Comment: @Stencil Except that JohnPS's answer is wrong.  Using `cin.good()` will not work in general; this function has, in fact, no known use.

Comment: That's true. But I acknowledge the fact he mentioned the nop operation replacing the normally expected code of cin after a failed read and cin.clear() to clear the reading buffer. And by the way, thank you for the long explanation (I was pleased that you explained the getchar() matter).

Answer (score 2):

You probably hit enter after the first character. You don't have any code to consume that enter, so you get an empty string. Your code doesn't expect any separator between the two inputs, so don't enter any.

Comment: That can't be right, since he's using `>>`, which skips leading white space (including new lines).

Comment: @JamesKanze: He has a `getchar` that he added that's not in the code he posted.

Comment: @David Schwartz: I just added another program, I haven't ever modified the first.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a `char` and wanted to read an `int`, the `cin` stream will have its `failbit` set. Calling `cin.fail()` will return `true` if the operation failed (ether `failbit` or `badbit` is set). You can act accordingly from there.

Note that `cin` can be converted to `bool` for testing, and according to the standard this boolean value is the same as `!cin.fail()`, and `!cin` is the same as `cin.fail()`. Both of the following are the same, but some people may consider the second more readable.

```
if(!cin) {
  // cin is in failed state
}

if(cin.fail()) {
  // cin is in failed state
}
```

Once `cin` is in a fail state, any read operation with `cin` will be a no-op until you reset the stream to a good state. You can do that by calling `cin.clear()`.

But you must also realize that the offending characters are still in the stream. That is, the non-integer character that caused the failed state will still be in the stream. How you handle this depending on how you want to recover from the error. One possibility is to call

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This will clear out the current line. Then you can prompt for the input again.

Comment: -1 for suggesting using `cin.good()`.  This is never the correct solution, because it may return false even if the results are correct.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, I should have said to check `cin.fail()` which is the same as `!cin`.