# assigning char to int reference and const int reference in C++

Tags: c++, reference, casting, constants, c++03

I noticed that assigning a `char` to a `const int&` compiles, but assigning it to a `int&` gives a compilation error.

```
char c;
int& x = c;    // this fails to compile
const int& y = c;    // this is ok
```

I understand that it is not a good practice to do this, but I am curious to know the reason why it happens.

I have searched for an answer by looking for "assigning to reference of different type", "assigning char to a int reference", and "difference between const reference and non-const reference", and came across a number of useful posts ([int vs const int&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705593/int-vs-const-int) , [Weird behaviour when assigning a char to a int variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716894/weird-behaviour-when-assigning-a-char-to-a-int-variable) , [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c) , [Difference between reference and const reference as function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719818/difference-between-reference-and-const-reference-as-function-parameter)), but they do not seem to be addressing my question.

My apologies if this has been already answered before.

Comment: @downvoter would you mind explaining the reason? I want to learn how I can improve the quality of my questions here, since I plan to visit this site regularly. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int& x = c;
```

Here an implicit conversion from `char` to `int` is being performed by the compiler. The resulting temporary `int` can only be bound to a `const` reference. Binding to a `const int&` will also extend the lifetime of the temporary result to match that of the reference it is bound to.

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is justified in the standard [N4527](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) at *8.5.3/p5.2 References [dcl.init.ref]*

> 5 A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type
>   “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> ...
>
> 5.2 Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a
>   non-volatile const type (i.e., cv1 shall be const), or the reference
>   shall be an rvalue reference. [ Example:
>
> ```
> double& rd2 = 2.0; // error: not an lvalue and reference not const
> int i = 2;
> double& rd3 = i; // error: type mismatch and reference not const
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the line

```
const int& y = c;
```

creates a temporary and `y` binds to the temporary can be verified by the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   char c = 10;
   const int& y = c;

   std::cout << (int)c << std::endl;
   std::cout << y << std::endl;

   c = 20;

   std::cout << (int)c << std::endl;
   std::cout << y << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10
10
20
10
```

The value of `y` did not change when the value of `c` was changed.